# Loading bitmap with RGB565 Config

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm loading my bitmaps with preferred config RGB565 from my assets folder and logging their format config but i'm always getting ARGB8888.I'm sure about some of my bitmap's config is RGB565 but i think they covers an area like an ARGB8888 bitmap.How can i load them with their own formats?

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
Log.d("a", fileName+" "+bitmap.getConfig().name());
```

Comment: ["preferred"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig) does not mean you will always get it. Your device can choose to not give you that format

Comment: Okey but how can i load bitmaps as RGB565 format from my assets folder?

Comment: The code you have written should work fine.

Comment: @Doomsknight I'm always getting ARGB8888 from Logs.No change with options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont always get RGB565 that way - it depends on the encoding (its a preferred encoding)

After loading the bitmap you can create a new one and copy it to there... as you are effectively re-encoding the image.

```
Bitmap maskBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( orig.getWidth(), orig.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 );
Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(maskBitmap);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setFilterBitmap(true); // possibly not nessecary as there is no scaling
c.drawBitmap(orig,0,0,p);
orig.recycle();
```

Then you can use maskBitmap as the loaded bitmap.

Comment: Thank you but isn't that will increase loading time very much?

Comment: @droidmachine and increasing the memory usage. Which is VERY BAD.

Comment: @Doomsknight Okey but isn't there a solution for loading bitmaps as rgb565?Actually my purpose is using this bitmap with opengl's glTex2D function and reduce memory use.What can i do about that?

Comment: @siliconeagle I didn't marked down.I just removed the accepted answer check.

I just want to use RGB565 bitmaps when ARGB8888 is not needed.How can i do this?

Comment: thats what this code does. You have to CONVERT THE IMAGE. Simialr the scaling it - you have to allocate the new piece of memory and the copy the re-encoded pixels into it. Thats how you do it. Yes it uses more memory while you are loading bitmaps but after that the ARGB8888 bitmaps are de-allocated(orig.recycle()) and the remaining bitmap is RGB565.

Comment: it does sound contra-logical but whenever you convert an image you have to allocate another bitmap to hold the result.

Comment: @siliconeagle So where is the memory problem like Doomsknight said? recycle() de-allocate memory and removes bitmap from memory so there isn't any leak.I just want to convert it and use with glTex2D.After that i'm recycling all the bitmaps already.

Comment: Its not a leak, its having two bitmaps in memory at the same time thats the problem. Even if it is a short while. Bitmaps can be huge in size, and just one is capiable of Out of memory. Two just doubles the chance. If you follow this info to keep bitmap size small, you should be ok. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html Im surprised your original code doesn't work.