# Android unknown bitmap configuration

Tags: android

I've got error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13921): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown bitmap configuration
E/AndroidRuntime(13921):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13921):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:939)
E/AndroidRuntime(13921):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:912)
E/AndroidRuntime(13921):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
E/AndroidRuntime(13921):    at com.ScalaView.onMeasure(ScalaView.java:46)
```

The code :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int w = widthMeasureSpec, h = heightMeasureSpec;

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; // see other conf types
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    currentHeight = canvas.getHeight();
    drawLines(canvas);
    setImageBitmap(bmp);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

I just create a blank bitmap. Why i got this error?

Comment: Do u need to use 'bmp factory' or a builder in oder to construct the config?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058905/converting-bitmap-in-memory-to-bitmap-with-bitmap-config-rgb-565